# Hide a table and change some text

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, jira

I need to write a little Javascript to hide a table (by adding the hidden style class) and then change the text of the link to represent the state. The hiding part works but the changing of text does not. Here's the javascript...

```
 function toggle(idToHide, hiderID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(idToHide);
    var hiddenClass = " hidden";
    if(element.getClassName().contains(hiddenClass)) {
       document.getElementById(hiderID).innerHTML = "Hide";
       element.className = element.className.replace(hiddenClass,'');
    } else {
       document.getElementById(hiderID).innerHTML = "Show";
       element.className += hiddenClass;
    }
  }
```

...and the Markup...

```
<a id="mercurial.repos.inactive.hider" href="#" onclick="toggle('mercurial.repos.inactive', 'mercurial.repos.inactive.hider'); return false;">Hide</a>

<table id="mercurial.repos.inactive">...</table>
```

Any clue as to why it wouldn't be changing the text of the hider link? If I run the specific line from the console, it works fine.

This is part of a JIRA Plugin if that makes any difference.

Comment: Why is there a space before `hidden`?

Comment: @meder - OP is using the same string to test for and concatenate or remove the class. I don't think it would be an issue as long as `getClassName()` doesn't trim the resulting string.

Comment: No, no errors on console. It seems like `document.getElementById(hiderID).innerHTML = "Show";` isn't getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually abandoned this and simply replaced it with "Show/Hide" instead of trying to swap between the texts.

Answer (score 0):

Why `getClassName`?

Try:

```
if(element.className.contains(hiddenClass)) {
```

Also, maybe check for `hiddenClass = "hidden" // (No space)`
and then add a space and the class name when you do add it, like:

```
element.className += " " + hiddenClass;
```

Comment: This part works fine. It's the part that is supposed to change the link text that isn't working